# How to get month name from week number and year

Tags: mysql-5.5

I have a week number and a year (e.g. 34 and 2015). I want to get the name of the month to which the specified week belongs.

How can I do that?

Comment: week starting and ending can have different months.

Comment: What makes a week belong to a month? Starting day (if so Sunday or Monday)? Ending Day? Most of the days in the week are in month X? Please add some more detail to the question. I'm voting to close this question until it's clearer

Comment: @TomV A week start with Monday (0) and end at Sunday  (6). current week no 11 in  current year. The week No 11 is belong to which month? I need Month name like March.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this Perl logic:

```perl
my $time_piece_obj = Time::Piece->strptime('2016-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d');
my $ONE_WEEK = 604800;
my $wk_no=20;
$time_piece_obj += $wk_no*$ONE_WEEK;
my $month_name= $time_piece_obj->month;
print $month_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE('201534  Monday','%X%V %W')) month_name
```

Instead of hardcoding the values, you can pass dynamic value also.